# Picasso with paged ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have implemented a simple `ListView` with a `CircularImageView` and two `TextView`'s.
My adapter is implemented with the ViewHolder Pattern.

I have implemented if the last item in my `ListView` has been reached the next 25 data will be added to the adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

In `getView()` of the adapter I load an image with Picasso `Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(holder.imageViewPreview)`.

But my problem is, whenever new data is added to the adapter the first new image (the 26th for example) ist the same as the 1st.

A workarround is to download the images via Spring's RestTemplate, but this is very troublesome and much amount of code.

Is there a more elegant solution with paged `ListView` and Picasso?

What about `RecyclerView` with paging and Picasso?

Comment: The problem you are describing shouldn't happen, show your code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed `ListView` to `RecyclerView` and it works!